# Default search does not bring node reference field.

Tags: search, nodes

I have a node reference field in one content type.I am not getting the search result if I do search with this node reference field value.this field is an auto complete field.What i need is if i search this node reference field value i want the node that belongs to this field.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) This doesn't make much sense at the moment, could you try explaining it a bit better? What does _if i search this node reference field value_ mean, for example?

Comment: k.I'll make it clear.i have a content type 'story' and another one 'product'.one of the field in 'story' content type references the 'product' node.I created a 'story' content 'abc' and a product content 'xyz'.the 'abc' content has a node reference field.its value is 'xyz'(auto complete field). if i am searching with this node reference field value ex:'xyz' in drupal default search form i am only getting 'product' content 'xyz' as results.instead i need story content 'abc'.